# Django IntegrityError; NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: django

I am trying to save an instance of a model but to no avail.

Below is my model;

```
class AudioFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    audio_file = models.FileField()
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(User,default='')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have the below form;

```
class AudioFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AudioFile
        fields = ['name', 'audio_file']

    def clean_audio_file(self):
        audio = self.cleaned_data['audio_file']
        if audio:
            if audio._size > 5*1024*1024:
                raise ValidationError("File too large ( > 5mb )")
            if os.path.splitext(audio.name)[1] != ".mp3":
                raise ValidationError("We only support mp3!")
            return audio
        else:
            raise validationError("Couldn't read uploaded file")
```

And I have the below view to handle the submitted form;

```
form = AudioFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.cleaned_data['uploader'] = request.user //view requires login
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse('home_audio',kwargs={'pk':audio_file.pk})
            )
    else:
        return HttpResponse(form.errors)
```

But on submission I get the error; `IntegrityError at /uploadaudio
NOT NULL constraint failed: stationrunner_audiofile.uploader_id` `/uploadaudio` is the URL correspoding to the view and `stationrunner` is my app's name.

Someone please help out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the view:

```
form = AudioFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    audio_file = form.save(commit=False) // This will not hit the database, and no IntegrityError will be raised
    audio_file.uploader = request.user  // Tack on the user, 
    audio_file.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(
        reverse_lazy('home_audio',kwargs={'pk':audio_file.pk}) // Use reverse lazy to prevent circular import issues.
    )
else:
    return HttpResponse(form.errors)
```

Also you could fix some issues with the model:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class AudioFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) // If the field is not allowed to be blank, the default blank does not make sense.
    audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to="audio_files") // Without this parameter file field does not work.
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) // This should reference the user model declared in your settings file.

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Thanx man changing the view as you suggested did the trick. But I'd like to know how is `uploader = models.ForeignKey(User, default'')` different from the one you suggest. Also `upload_to="some/location" is no more required`, Django 1.7 onwards. The one who told me of this said he considers it a good practice though.

Comment: The default setting blank string is invalid, as Foreign Keys are represented by integer and will only lead to confusion. Additionally, the user model should always be referenced by the settings auth user, to make the app more reusable. If you'd like to reuse this in the future, or let other people reuse it, they won't have to swap out the user model. Thanks for letting me know about the upload_to not being required any more.

Comment: What if I need to have relation to a custom model? Then I'll need to go with `models.ForeignKey(ModelName, default='')` right?

Comment: If you mean custom user model, then no. The code I posted will work just fine. The default="" setting makes no sense to me, because Foreign Keys cannot be empty strings.

Comment: Simply a custom model, any model. I'm only learning Django. I don't remember the exact message but without `default=''` on `ForeignKey` relation, I was being asked to give a default value for some reason when trying to do `makemigrations` and hence `default=''`

Comment: Hm. I had it for all the relations but I removed and the said message did not pop up. Guess the reason was something else! Thanks man. I have that confusion out now.